# How to customize VTiger CRM from Style.less

Tags: css, vtiger, vtigercrm

I am relatively new to VTiger CRM due to project that has been assigned.

I am facing an issue, we are supposed to give VTiger certain customization by setting up a color in my case is "RED", I have been doing some research and I was able to find out that the colors can be modified in the "style.less" file through CSS however I have no experience in CSS and would not know how to get started.

I used the "inspect" option in my browser to discover the element of the website and know what I am looking for in the "style.less" file but even after making changes on the file it does not reflect the changes as I would expect it to do so.

[This is what i mean by the inspect option.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSkV5.png)

[I have the Vtiger file open in Visual Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RrA8Z.png)

Hope I can get some advise to have the color udpated.

NEW PHOTOS HERE!!!

[This is what I see when going to inspect in Edge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3KLY.png)

[This is path of the Style.less file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQs3r.png)

[So I went ahead and open said path in VsCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qSaBC.png)

Comment: Mouse over the name of style.less when you inspect and make sure the file path is exacly the file your are modifying. Also use Ctrl+F5 to hard refresh the page and make sure the cache is clean. If you know how to rename that file and also update the refrences to that file, that would be better to make sure it is not cached.

Comment: Thank you for the advise. I have done as instructed but the dificult part for me at least, is that I cannot figure out which one out of all in the style.less file needs to be updated. I have stoped the Apache server in which I hosted VTiger and started it again deleted cache but changes are still not going through. I read something about locating the class so I can know for sure where to make the changes but no success so far

Comment: When you inspect the elemnt, for each css rule the name of file is also shown on top of the css rules. mouse over that file name and find the full path of that file.

Comment: I went ahead and completed all that's been advised but the Style.less file do exists but in this particular path: "C:/xampp/htdocs/vtigercrm" but the path when going into Inspect mode in Edge is shown as  "C:/xampp/htdocs/vtigercrmcode". Should I have that specific path or can changes be done in the path I have?.....Cuz that second path I indicated does not exist in my files

Comment: I have added as well some screenshots so you can take a look and hopefully help me!